# c# console apps passing arguments

Tags: c#, console, command-line-arguments

I got this far:

```
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\a\a.exe");
procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
procInfo.Arguments = "01";
procInfo.Arguments = user_number;
procInfo.Arguments = email;
Process.Start(procInfo);
```

But it only passes one argument (being the last one to overwrite), how do I pass more then one argument, the args on the console is an array, this must mean i can pass more then one argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to pass a single string of space-separated arguments:

```
procInfo.Arguments = "01 " + user_number + " " + email;
```

The same thing, using a format:

```
procInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", "01", user_number, email);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ..

```
procInfo.Arguments = "01 " + user_number + " " + email;
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's right about just needing to concatenate. Just a stylistic thing but you can use String.Join to make passing the arguments a bit more elegant:

```
        string[] argv = {"01", user_email, email};
        ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\a\a.exe");
        procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        procInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", argv);
        Process.Start(procInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate your arguments into a single string that a delimited by a space? Or you could use some sort of identifier before each argument and have the .exe application parse the string.